# Illustrator: copying an artboard to a new document

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a document with dozens of artboards. I would like to copy a single artboard into a new document, preserving its content and dimensions. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Do save as EPS or Ai and choose range, and select your art board number.

Comment: Eddie, you can't "use artboards" when saving as an Ai file (and EPS might not save all the work).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can save a single Artboard in the Illustrator Options window.
Go to `File > Save As` and then choose a path, and then select OK. The next window will look like this:
[image: Illustrator Options]
Just check the `Save each artboard to a separate file` box, and then specify the artboard number in the `Range` box.
**NOTE:** The final file will be saved with the artboard number appended to the end such as `example-02.ai`.

Comment: What if you wanted to copy the artboard and it's artwork to an existing (but different) file?

Comment: @dumbledad I don't think that is directly possible, but if I was trying to accomplish that, I would note the source artboard dimensions, and create a new artboard with those dimensions in the destination file. Then, with the artboard selected in the source doc, select the artboard contents and `Ctrl-C` copy them. Then, on the destination doc, with the artboard selected, `Ctrl-F` will paste in front. NOTE: This will not retain layers, but everything will be in the same place relative to the artboard.

Answer (score 5):

- Save As...
- Title the document something new
- Delete all unwanted artboards and art
- Save

I would not recommend saving as .eps unless you know the artwork will be flattened correctly. And saving as .ai does **not** provide the option to pick and choose artboards to save.

Comment: or indeed marqee select whats on the board hit ctrl+c and paste it to a new document.

Comment: @joojaa that's straightforward but often the exact dimensions of the board are important and it's (seemingly) laborious to copy the dimensions across by hand.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've found so far is just to make a blank artboard in the new document, making sure Illustrator is focused on that artboard. Then in the document you're transferring the artboard from, select the artwork in the artboard making sure that Illustrator focuses on that artboard as well. 'Copy' (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) from the original document and 'Paste in Place' (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) in the new document.

Comment: This was my default way of doing it, but I found it finicky and time consuming, especially if I wanted to make sure the artboard's dimensions were exactly the same in the new document. I don't think this is the fastest way of doing it, but it's easy to learn and understand. Thanks.

Comment: doesn't preserve layers either

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the OP found the answer to this question already, but if anyone else happened to come across this page like I did, watch this Youtube video below for the answer!

- Make a new artboard in a new file,
- Go back to the file with the artboard you're trying to copy,
- In that same file, click the artboard tool,
- Click the artboard you're trying to duplicate,
- Select > All on Active Artboard >
- Edit > Copy,
- Go back to the new file, click on the new artboard you created in the beginning,
- Edit > Paste in Place (so that it will be on the new artboard and not in some random place if you were to click regular paste).

[Adobe Illustrator How To Copy Artwork To A New Illustrator Document](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yj8WdqZa7bc)

Comment: Hi HiThere! This is indeed a clean and tidy way to move an art board to a new doc. (A key part for me, at least, was to preserve the dimensions of the art board, as mine were often arbitrarily sized.)

Answer (score 0):

People have probably figured it out with newer versions of Illustrator. I don't have CC but with CS6 go to 'File → New From Template' and search for your saved AI file.

Answer (score 0):

In illustrator 2022, I just select all artboards that I want to copy to another file and drag them to that file's tab.